# Bosh CEPH Blobstore

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud-foundry, blobstore, ceph, cf-bosh

My team wants to store the blobs for our BOSH release in a remote blobstore. However we have an internal CEPH / Rados store that we want to use. I know that Rados has S3 compatible interfaces so I was wondering how I could enable this as the final blobstore.

I know that typically I'd only need to give the access key, secrete key, and bucket to BOSH. But now I also have an IP host (and probably in the future a url) that specifies where the bucket exists. Is there currently a way to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example on how BOSH can interact with a CEPH / Rados store:

**Storing packages in an internal CEPH / Rados store**

This requires configuring the release to know about the intended blobstore. Keep in mind that when you run `bosh upload blobs` the command is parsed by the BOSH CLI rather than a BOSH or MicroBOSH VM if you have happened to target one. Assume that you have a store at address `IP_ADDRESS:PORT` with an existent bucket named `BUCKET` and keys `ACCESS_KEY` and `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. The `config/final.yml` file should look like:

```
---
blobstore:
  provider: s3
  options:
    bucket_name: BUCKET
    host: IP_ADDRESS
    s3_port: PORT
```

But the `config/private.yml` file should look like:

```
---
blobstore:
  s3:
    access_key_id: ACCESS_KEY
    secret_access_key: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Depending on how the CEPH store is set up, it may be necessary to turn off ssl verification as well which would include adding `ssl_verify_peer: false` under the `s3_port` option (i.e. the nesting would be `blobstore` -> `s3` -> `ssl_verify_peer`. At this point calling `bosh upload blobs` will work as expected.

**Telling a BOSH VM about the CEPH / Rados store**
The deployment manifest file needs to have the items in the private.yml and the bucket name in the blobstore properties section.

**EDIT Aug 20, 2015**
According to the CEPH website http://ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/#api there is currently no support for Bucket policies. Therefore the fact that a bucket is readable will not be inherited by a bucket's objects. This means that if a CEPH store is used in place of the official Amazon S3 for storage, the `config/private.yml` file is mandatory.